# DOMXPath/DOM - Check if can find the element in the DOM

Tags: dom, domdocument, domxpath

Here is my code:

```
$url = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/football-shirts/premier-league-football-shirts/arsenal-football-shirts";    

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$n  = $xpath->query('//div[@class="s-producttext-top-wrapper"]');
$l  = $xpath->query('//div[@class="s-producttext-top-wrapper"]/a');
$p  = $xpath->query('//div[@class="s-largered"]');
$im  = $xpath->query('//a[@class="ProductImageList"]');
$ra = $xpath->query('//div[@class="s-producttext-review"]/div');

$nl = $xpath->query('//a[@class="swipeNumberClick"][last()]')->item(0)->C14N();

echo $nl;
```

How can i check if `$nl` finds the element in the DOM ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As [XPath:query()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domxpath.query.php) returns an instance of [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domnodelist.php), you can check [length](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domnodelist.php#domnodelist.props.length) attribute in order check if any node was found:

```
$nl = $xpath->query('//a[@class="swipeNumberClick"][last()]');
# or $nl->length > 0
if ($nl->length) {
    $nl = $nl->item(0)->C14N();
}
```